# single quotes not escaping in category_description

Tags: categories, low-seg2cat

I am having trouble with single quotes being output in my category_description field, i have attempted removing them using ce_string without success.

Also i am outputting category_description through low Seg2Cat.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a go at it using [low replace](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace)? Guess it will be the same as ce_string but worth a try.

Also, could you post the actual code you are working with. Would likely help others understanding what's going on.